# Achartengine, set different color for bars in a barchart

Tags: android

I'm using achartengine to draw a bar chart and I want different colors for each bar based on the value from the y axis like, if value > 100, color = red

so my chart looks somewhat like this.

[image]

So, is it possible to achieve this with achartengine?

Regards.

Edit: Here's my code so far,

```
public class GraphActivity extends Activity {

LinearLayout chart;
private View mChart;
private static final int SERIES_NR = 2;
int[] income = {102, 95, 97, 100, 92, 99, 88};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
    chart = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getTruitonBarRenderer();
    myChartSettings(renderer);
    mChart = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(this, getTruitonBarDataset(), renderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
    chart.addView(mChart);
}

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getTruitonBarDataset() {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    final int nr = 4;
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] x = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("INCOME");
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        series.add(income[i]);
    }
    dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
    return dataset;
}

public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getTruitonBarRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(50);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(25);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    return renderer;
}

private void myChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0.8);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(7.1);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(50);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(220);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Tue");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Wed");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Thu");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "Fri");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "Sat");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "Sun");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Today");
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setBarWidth((float)25);

    renderer.setShowAxes(false);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);

    renderer.setMargins(new int[] {0,50,0,20});

    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setShowGridY(false);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(0); // sets the number of integer labels to appear
}
```

}

This is how it looks like now..
[image: this is how it looks like now]

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: dont know how to give different colors based on value

Comment: @TimCastelijns I've updated my question, hope you got it now

Comment: @HeisenBerg Did you find any solution for this.?

Comment: Yes I did, I used another library called MPAndroidChart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by using another library called [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

In MPAndroidChart you can define the values and color as an array.

Let's say the chart contains 7 bars. Then you can define values and color as

```
values[6] = {50, 34, 34, 57, 34, 34, 56}
color[6] = {red, green, blue, black, yellow, orange, purple}
```

so the first bar will take red color, second bar will take green color, third bar will take blue color and so on.